# How to Add Spannable String to List preference Alert dialog

Tags: android

I am working on list Preferences,have to increase the font size in Alert Dialog which pops up when we click on ListPreference element,try to help me in this ........Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to adjust the controls in an AlertDialog, you will have to create and add your controls manually.

[AlertDialog reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My requirement is need to increase the font size in Alert Dialog, after searching i realized that it's possible with Sappanble String, but i dont know how to use it with List Preference AlertDialog.....Can you help me with any sample code.....